# No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/theme.AppCompat

Tags: android

I've viewed a ton of posts regarding this issue, but everything here checks out.

Code:

Actionbar:

`<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>`

Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 'android-L'
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}
`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev75-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v2-rev63-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
    compile files('libs/app-AppEngine-endpoints-android.jar')
}`

Using Android Studio

YES I have support library installed

YES I have tried moving SDK versions all the way up to sdk-18

**EDIT**

Ctrl-Clicking on the ".../Theme.AppCompat" takes me to the correct lines in values.xml, see below:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat">
    <item name="isLightTheme">false</item>

    <!-- Required for use of support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml -->
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">            @style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
    <item name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall</item>
    <item name="searchResultListItemHeight">58dip</item>
```

Comment: Have you added the support library as a reference to your project?

Comment: Isn't it right there in the gradle dependencies? compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20+'

Comment: In eclipse(not sure about Android Studio) you have to import the Library then make it into a reference to your project no matter what. Try that what do you have to lose.

Comment: This is all you need for Android Studio  https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Use `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`.

Comment: @Luksprog after changing it to this, an error occurred, but after I messed around with it I solved it. I will update that as the Answer when time lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this to parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat" causes an error, but by defining that theme in "styles" I managed to fix it at it worked as intended.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand.It is recommended to make use of comments to point out corrections or raise doubts once you earn enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your use of the @android prefix that's causing the problem. I struggled with it for ages until I found this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19507892/1123654